# Spring in pulley system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

[image]

Here the spring is being pulled by both ends by the tension force $T$. And it is well known that $T=kx$ where $x$ is the elongation of the spring. But i don't understand how. My teacher told me that since the spring is massless,the net force on the spring is $0$,hence $T-kx=0$. I have a bit problem understanding this.

First of all,there are two $T$ forces acting on the spring(*one is the upper $T$,the other is the lower $T$*). Also I don't understand how $kx$ is a force *applied on* the spring. Isn't it a restoring force that is inherent to the spring?Moreover,when a block is attached to a spring and the spring stretches by $x$,we say that $kx$ *is the force applied by spring ON the block*. We don't say that is applied on the spring. So i don't understand why this should be a force to draw in the free body diagram of the spring. The only forces that i can see in the free body diagram are the two tension forces at the two ends of the spring. Please enlighten me with the correct interpretation for $T=kx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the diagram below the magnitudes of the forces $T$ and $T'$ are the same.
The $T$ forces are a Newton third law pair and the $T'$ forces are a Newton third law pair.

[image]

Because the spring is massless there can be no net force on the spring and the two forces acting on it cause the extension $x$ such that $T=kx = T'$.

You may be puzzled by there being two forces acting on the spring as it is often the case that the top of the spring is connected to a fixed support and the force exerted on the spring by the fixed support is omitted.

The bottom left hand force is the force applied to the block via the string.

Answer (score 0):

The equality $T = k x$ can be considered as the constitutive law of a linear spring, i.e. the law that links the force applied with opposite direction at both ends of the spring, $T$, and the elongation of the spring itself.

The equilibrium of the spring is granted by the fact that the intensity of the forces applied at its ends is the same, while the directions are opposite.

Referring to your picture, when you attach a mass to the lower end of the spring, by action/reaction principle, you know that the force acting on the mass is $T$ pointing upwards, since the force acting on the spring is pointing downwards.